# Format tabular data with a certain row highlighted

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I have tried a method to highlight certain rows in various tableform.
An example:

```
product = {"Apple", "Banana", "Watermelone", "Strawberry"};
value = {5, 10, 40, 20};
percent = N[value/Total[value]];
rank = value /. Thread[# -> Ordering[#, All, Greater]] &@Union@value;
TableForm[Map[{#, product[[#]], value[[#]], 100*percent[[#]], rank[[#]]} &, Range[4]], TableHeadings -> {None, {"Serial Nr.", "Product", "Value", "%", 
"Ranking"}}, TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
```

It consists this table:

[image]

I’d like to automatically highlight data which meets bigger then the 50% and this table arrange in according to rank.

Finally a table would look like:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Go with `Grid`. There is an option `Background`, there is also a function `Sort/SortBy`. That's all you need to check. TableHeadings are nice feature but lack of others makes `Grid` better suited for your problem.

Comment: @Kuba can you maybe futher help with this grid...`Grid[Map[{#, product[[#]], value[[#]], 100*percent[[#]], rank[[#]]} &,
   Range[4]], Background -> Green]`.. thats not looking good :).. how can I use this sort or Sortby functions?

Comment: Type `Grid` then press F1, then go to `Options` section. The same with `Sort`.

Comment: Or you can use `Item`.

Comment: @Kuba `Grid[Map[{#, product[[#]], value[[#]], 100*percent[[#]], rank[[#]]} &,
   Range[4]], Frame -> All, Spacings -> {4, 0.5}, 
 Background -> {None, {3 -> Green}}]`.. i dont want to do it manuel like this.. is the no options that I do it automatically? if the percent more than 50% that can make it automatically green or what else..?

Comment: Please can someone help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily elegant or optimal, but this seems to work:

```
hdr = {"Serial Nr.", "Product", "Value", "%", "Ranking"};
serial = Range[Length[product]];
value = {5, 10, 40, 20};
percent = 100 N[value/Total[value]];
rank = value /. Thread[# -> Ordering[#, All, Greater]] &@Union@value;

data = Transpose[{serial, product, value, percent, rank}];
sorted = Sort[data, #1[[4]] > #2[[4]] &];

over50 = 1 + Pick[sorted[[All, 5]], Thread[sorted[[All, 4]] >= 50]];
coloring = Rule[#, Green] & /@ over50;

Grid[Prepend[sorted, hdr], Frame -> All, Spacings -> {4, 0.5},
    Alignment -> {{Left, Left, Right, ".", Left}, None}, 
    Background -> {None, coloring}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for ur answer..not mather its work :)